# Laptop boot failure

Tags: windows, boot, laptop-repair

My laptop won't boot past the Windows error recovery page, it just keeps cycling.  I have already tried running Windows 7 repair disk, and it was not able to fix an issues.  What would be my next step?

- I also get the error "internal hard disk drive not found" "no bootable devices" on startup
- I have taken out the hard drive and am testing it in another computer.  Whats a good program to test if the hard drive is failing?
- The computer is a Dell Inspiron 1750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the BIOS on the computer you are testing it with have a hard drive test on it? If so, normally that is the best tool to use. It sounds like you have a faulty hard drive. If you hear a ticking when the computer is on, that is one key indicator that the hard drive is bad. Also, the computer saying that there is no bootable device is a key indicator that the hard drive is bad.

The ticking noise that indicates a bad hard drive is caused from the read/write head pecking on the magnetic disk (in the hard drive). At this point there is nothing you can do. The hardware is just simply bad. This happens a lot unfortunately. If the computer is still under warranty, you can have the manufacturer send you another one for free.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip I am running a disk check on the hardrive right now, you are probably right.

Comment: Thanks for the accept! Let me know with a comment is you have any questions or problems. I will probably be on for another 20 minutes. If the drive is bad, normally the test will fail nearly immediately (depending on which program you are using).

Comment: good to know, it hasn't failed yet, but replacing the drive probably is still my only option.